# Ordinal not in range, but I can't find it: removing non-ASCII characters

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii

I had an error when I'm trying to convert a CSV to KML using minidom .toprettyxml with:

```
for row in csvReader:
    placemarkElement = createPlacemark(kmlDoc, row, order)
    documentElement.appendChild(placemarkElement)
kmlFile = open(fileName, 'w')
kmlFile.write(kmlDoc.toprettyxml('  ', newl='\n', encoding='utf-8'))
```

the error is:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position
>   5: ordinal not in range(128)

I had a lot of records, so decided to print out what it was that falls out of this range, as it doesn't seem to be 0xa0, so I used:

```
def removeNonAscii(s):
for i in s:
    if ord(i) > 128:
        sys.stdout.write("\r{0}".format(i) + '\n')
        sys.stdout.write("\r{0}".format(ord(i)) + '\n')
return "".join(i for i in s if ord(i) < 128)
```

to remove the offending chars from the output, and print out what they were.
The only thing that prints out is "á", with ordinal code 160.

I searched for this both in Notepad++ and in Excel, but cannot find it, so I don't understand where this is coming from?
I would rather know what I am removing with by removeNonAscii, in case it is important

I'm using utf-8 encoding if that helps

Comment: Show the code that's generating the error, not the code you wrote to try to debug it.

Comment: @Wooble I have included the code now, it wasn't included initially as I tried to make it as concise as possible

Comment: What encoding is your CSV file in? You probably need to decode it to `unicode` before passing it to whichever function is raising `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Comment: You input file is probably not ASCII but [Windows-1252](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoded.  `0xa0` is _non-breaking space_ in that encoding.